# (Pre)select checkboxes in a ListActivity using 'simple_list_item_checked'

Tags: android, checkbox, listactivity

I'm using the **ListActivity** class in conjunction with the **simple_list_item_checked**-layout which implements simple list items with **checkboxes**. Everything is working fine - clicking added items calls onListItemClick() and I can check/uncheck respective checkboxes of entries via the 'View v' parameter.

However what I wasn't able to figure out yet is, how to (pre)select checkboxes without any userinteraction?

Minimal so far working code snippet showing my intend:

```
package org.test;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> list_elems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked);
        list_elems.add("foobar");
        //TODO: check added entry labeled "foobar"
        setListAdapter(list_elems);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
           CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView)v;
        check.setChecked(!check.isChecked());
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

daten

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

You have to set the choicemode of the underlying ListView to single or multiple.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> list_elems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked);
        list_elems.add("foobar");
        //TODO: check added entry labeled "foobar"
        setListAdapter(list_elems);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        lv.setItemChecked(0, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SimpleListAdapter` as the ListAdapter for your ListActivity.  Use two columns (one for your string and the other for the checked value), and the system should take care of it by itself.  Here is a good [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: Thanks Sashi, however all these solution are using a cursor pointing to something like a database. I already have an array of Strings which I'd like to represent in that list. Is there any example that shows how to use a SimpleListAdapter with already existing non-database data?

Comment: Sorry about the misdirection, I meant to say SimpleAdapter.  You pass in a array of maps and you can tell it which element from the map to use for each element of the view.  Just replace the cursor parameter in the example with a list of maps (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>)